# Assertion on a collection of entries in single pass

Tags: java

Is it possible to assert on an entire collection based on a set of conditions on its entries.
Let us have a List of Employees.

```
List<Employee>
```

My  test case needs to validate that all the values in the list fulfill one of the conditions:

```
If age > 60 then status == Status.Retired
If age < 18 then status == Status.Student
```

Was trying to explore if this is possible with `foreach` and lambda:

```
Consumer<Employee> lambdaExpression = x ->
                (x.getAge() < 18 && x.getStatus == Status.Student) ||
                (x.getAge() > 60 && x.getStatus == Status.Retired)||
                (x.getAge() > 18 && x.getAge() < 60
                                 && x.getStatus==Status.Employed);
assertTrue(params.forEach((n) -> lambdaExpression));
```

Is this possible in some way?

Comment: Note: enum values are considered constants, and therefore should, according to the Java Naming Conventions, be written in UPPER_SNAKE_CASE. For instance, `Employed` should be `EMPLOYED`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a stream and `allMatch`:

```
Predicate<Employee> predicate = 
               emp -> (emp.getAge() <= 60 && emp.getAge() >= 18 
                                          && Status.Employed == emp.getStatus()) 
                   || (emp.getAge() > 60 && Status.Retired == emp.getStatus())
                   || (emp.getAge() < 18 && Status.Student == emp.getStatus()) 

assertTrue(params.stream().allMatch(predicate));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a test library called [assertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/). You can then write a code something like:

```
assertThat(params).allSatisfy(param -> <your conditions here>);
```

Or dozens of other kinds of assertions in this scheme

Answer (score 0):

You can trick use filter to get list of non-matching element of list and compare for size 0.

```
Predicate<Employee> predicate = emp -> (emp.getAge() <= 60 && emp.getAge() >= 18 ) 
                              || (emp.getAge() > 60 && "retired".equals(emp.getStatus())
                              || (emp.getAge() < 18 && "status".equals(emp.getStatus()) 

assertTrue(params.stream().filter(!predicate).collect(Collectors.toList()).isEmpty());
```

Comment: this solution is not too elegant. You don't need to check if the size is 0, you can call `isEmpty()`.
Also, you don't even have to make a list, you can use something like `ernest_k` used, the `allMatch()` function

Comment: just another approach. ernest_k's answer is surely more elegant and using streams to best.